# Json Schema - Using enumerations using reference

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm trying to construct a [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/example2.html) for my use case where I have the enumerations for a string in a separate file and want to refer that from my schema. How can I achieve that.

Sample Schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "card": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "value": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": {"$ref" : "reference to a file having list of enums"}
                  //I want to refer to a specific enum array (say value1's array)
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "card"
    ]
}
```

Enums file is like:

```
{
"value1": [..],
"value2": [..]
....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$ref` should only be used to reference schemas.  So, you could do something like this.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "card": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": { "type": "integer" },
                "value": { "$ref" : "/schemas/valueEnum.json" }
            }
        }
    },
    "required": ["card"]
}
```

/schemas/valueEnum.json

```
{ "enum": ["foo", "bar"] }
```